# Get only one value of a constantly polling shell command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to get network traffic data to display in my DWM statusbar but i only need one single value.
Most network traffic shell tools constantly polls data over second

here is my implementation so far:

```
# _wifi.sh

# Conection report

bmon -p wlo1 -o format:fmt='$(attr:txrate:bytes)'

kill "$(pstree -lp | grep -oe bmon\([0-9]*\) | sed 's/[^0-9]//g')"
```

But obviously doesn't work because when bmon starts it doesn't stop util i hit CTRL+C

```
0.00
0.00
0.00
86.01
21.50
69.90
17.47
4.37
127.84
^C
```

How can i get only 1 single value and then kill it asynchronously?

Comment: Why don't you pipe its output to `head -n 1`?

Comment: Unfortunally doesn't work, it outputs nothing. My guess is that bmon takes a while to start polling and head can't read anything

Comment: Weird. I don't have bmon installed, so can't help any further. Good luck

Comment: maybe `bmon -o format:quitafter=1` can help. [source](https://github.com/tgraf/bmon/issues/29)

Comment: How can i chain that with the format string?

Comment: try with `;` e.g `bmon -o format:quitafter=1;fmt='$(attr:txrate:bytes)'`

Comment: doesn't work, i've tryied this already :/

Answer (score 0):

Add a second output module (format). The first output is typically zero, so I use value 2 in quitafter.

`bmon -p wlo1 -o format:fmt='$(attr:txrate:bytes)' -o format:quitafter=2`